# Algebraic proof with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to proof the following:

> Given $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix so that $A^2 - 3A + I = 0$
>
> Prove that $A^{-1} = 3I - A$

So I laid out a matrix:
$$
A =\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Which (I think) means that:

$$
a^2+bc-3a+1=0 \leftrightarrow \frac{d}{ad-bc}=3-a $$
$$
ab+bd-3b=0 \leftrightarrow \frac{-b}{ad-bc}=-b$$
$$
ca+dc-3c=0 \leftrightarrow \frac{-c}{ad-bc}=-c$$
$$
d^2+bc-3d+1=0 \leftrightarrow \frac{a}{ad-bc}=3-d$$

Does all this mean that $ad-bc =1$? If so, then $d=3-a$ and $a=3-d$, right? Thus:

$$
a^2+bc-3a+1=0 \leftrightarrow d=3-a $$
$$
ab+bd-3b=0$$
$$
ca+dc-3c=0$$
$$
d^2+bc-3d+1=0 \leftrightarrow a=3-d$$
But I've only gotten this far. I'm pretty new to formal proof so I have no idea what to do now. Could anyone help me?

Sorry, I really suck at this.

Comment: Have you learnt operations on matrices? For example, pre/post multiplication of matrices in an equation.

Comment: What if you multiplied the matrix equation by $A^{-1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No assumption that A need be invertible:

\begin{align*}A^2-3A+I=0 &\Rightarrow I = 3A -A^2 \\
&\Rightarrow I = A(3I-A) = (3I-A)A \\
&\Rightarrow A \; \textrm{is invertible and} \; A^{-1} = 3I-A\end{align*}

Comment: Hey, I saw your comment in BlackAdder's reply, it makes perfect sense. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: No worries, glad to help!

Comment: I have a question, you assume $A(3I-A)=(3I-A)A$ because $A^{-1}A=AA^{-1}=I$, right?

Comment: That's just because $A$ commutes with itself and the identity, so it doesn't matter if we pre- or post-multiply in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply: $A*(3I - A) = 3AI - A^2 = 3A - (3A - I) = 3A - 3A + I = I$, and

$(3I - A)*A = 3IA - A^2 = 3A - A^2 = 3A - (3A - I) = 3A - 3A + I = I$. This means:

$A^{-1} = 3I - A$.